# How to remove a list from one number to another using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, each

I have the following structure:

```
<ul id="ip-top-menu">
    <li>Doesn't exclude</li>
    <li>Doesn't exclude</li>
    <li>
        <span>Doesn't exclude</span>
        <ul>
            <li>Doesn't exclude</li>
            <li>Doesn't exclude</li>
            <li>Doesn't exclude</li>
            <li>Exclude this</li>
            <li>Exclude this</li>
            <li>Exclude this</li>
            <li>Exclude this</li>
            <li>Exclude this</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <ul>
            <li>Doesn't exclude</li>
        </ul>
    </li> 
</ul>
```

And I would like to delete

from the 4th to the last, the 10th. How do I do that using jquery?
I tried, but doesn't work:

```
$('#ip-top-menu > li:eq(2) > ul').each(function (index, element) {
             if ( $(this).is("li:eq(2)") ) {
                $(element).remove();
                return false;
             }
          });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done with a single selector string. Target the `<li>` indicies with `:nth-child`, which can accept an equation (and not just a number, like `:eq` does). For the outer `<li>`, use `:nth-child(3)`; for the descendant `<li>`s, use `:nth-child(n + 4)` to select the 4th, 5th, 6th, etc.

```js
$('#ip-top-menu > li:nth-child(3) li:nth-child(n + 4)').remove();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="ip-top-menu">
  <li>Doesn't exclude</li>
  <li>Doesn't exclude</li>
  <li>
    <span>Doesn't exclude</span>
    <ul>
      <li>Doesn't exclude</li>
      <li>Doesn't exclude</li>
      <li>Doesn't exclude</li>
      <li>Exclude this</li>
      <li>Exclude this</li>
      <li>Exclude this</li>
      <li>Exclude this</li>
      <li>Exclude this</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <ul>
      <li>Doesn't exclude</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: What is the "n" of the li:nth-child(n + 4) ?

Comment: See https://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/ - it'll match elements when `n` is substituted with 0, 1, 2, etc. Here, that's equivalent to: `nth-child(4)` merged with `nth-child(5)`, `nth-child(6)`, etc.